# php query_mysql don't return anything

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to delete a row from database and i`m using the following code. When i submit the page reloads and if  i check the db the row is still there. No error, no nothing. What can i do to solve this?

HTML

```
<div class="delete_row">
    Sterge
    <form method="post" action="">
    *<input type="text" name="id_col" Placeholder="Id-ul coloanei"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Sterge">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
$id_stergere=isset($_POST["id_col"]);
$submitcheck2=isset($_POST["submit1"]);

if($submitcheck2 && $id_stergere !==0 ){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM evenimente WHERE ID_even=$id_stergere";
    $result = query_mysql($sql);
}
```

Comment: You ask about `mysql_query` in your title but in your code there is only `query_mysql` and `$id_stergere` is either `true` or `false` but not an id.

Comment: it is query_mysql i'm sorry, and is it false or true? doesn't it get the value from the input?

Comment: You know that there is a documentation? [php: isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: if i delete `isset` it gives me the following error `Notice: Undefined index: id_col in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST["id_col"]))
    $id_stergere=$_POST["id_col"];

if (isset($_POST["submit1"]))
    $submitcheck2=$_POST["submit1"];

//additional check:
// if (!is_numeric($id_stergere)) die('there was a problem');
// if (!$submitcheck2) die('there was a problem');

    $sql = "DELETE FROM evenimente WHERE ID_even=".$id_stergere;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

query_mysql?

Use this for your php :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

    $id_stergere=$_POST["id_col"];
    $submitcheck2=$_POST["submit1"];

    if($submitcheck2 && $id_stergere){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM evenimente WHERE ID_even=$id_stergere";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

You should be using mysqli instead though.

Use this instead of the `$sql = and $result = :`

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","db","password","user") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$query= "DELETE FROM evenimente WHERE ID_even=$id_stergere";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

To get the numrows use this:

```
$numrows = $result->num_rows;
```

For a fetch_array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

      $var= $row['field'];
}
```

UPDATE: Add e`rror_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` to the top of php script.

Comment: `isset` returns a `bool` as of that `$id_stergere` will never be an _id_, it will be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I don't understand why do i need fetch_array if i just want to delete it? Can you explain me, please?

Comment: You don't, that is just for further reference with mysqli as is the numrows.

Comment: Without telling that you removed `isset`  and why it is like a spot the difference game. And `isset($_POST["submit1"])` was not wrong - at least it does not look as it is wrong.

Comment: And how can i fix that notice? `Notice: Undefined index: id_col in...`? It show up when i remove isset from the variable `$id_stergere`

Comment: If the button was pressed then it means that the id was also sent. You only have to check for the button, the id check comes later on in the script.

Comment: Add this to the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`